# Is the access to the top-level page table random?

Tags: operating-system

The top-level page table will not occupy all its table items. What happens when I access a table item with "in / out of place" of 0?

I see that the processing method given in the book is to force a page missing interrupt, but this page missing interrupt is different from what I think. It may directly end the process. Why not remap it?

In addition, if the access to the top-level page table is random (I think the virtual address can be large), For example, in this case in the figure, it is obvious that there are many empty table items in the top-level page table.Isn't it easy to miss?

[image]

I think I can extract the key point of the problem, that is, is there a certain virtual address after the program is compiled? Can the operating system try to ensure that it does not cross the border to access unmapped addresses?

I think I have found the answer. After compiling, the program will set logical addresses for them, and the page table items of the top-level page table also correspond to the logical memory distribution of the program. For example, the program body is at the bottom, the corresponding page table item is 0, and the last item of the page table corresponds to the stack area of the program. Once the program accesses the page table items without mapping, it means that it accesses an address area that should not be accessed, I wonder if my idea is correct?

I'm sorry that my English level may make it difficult for you to understand. Thank you for your answer!